# URL Rewrite in wodpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, redirect

I am trying to rewrite URL in multi-language WordPress web site.

Problem is in homepage URL. When web site is in english, everything is ok, but whet I switch to Slovakian, I get this URL for homepage:
**www.example.com/sk/home/**

but I want it to be:
**www.example.com/sk/**

I tried adding this in .htacess, and it didnt work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sk?$ sk/home
```

Based on https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/ 
I tried adding in functions.php, but also didn't work

```
function rewrite_sk() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^sk', 'sk/home', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'rewrite_sk');
```

Anybody knows where I am making mistake? Because I can't figure it out.

Comment: After adding rewrite rules did you flush the permalinks settings?

Answer (score 0):

try to regenerate permalinks.

Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

First update your permalink
[image: Frist try this]

Then select your home
[image: img 2]